# Добавить элемент в массив структур Си

Tags: c

Массив структур хранится в файле. В начале файла храню число с количеством записей.
Необходимо добавить новую запись в массив структур (первый пункт меню).
Для этого считываю структуру из файла функцией load. Передаю указатель на структуру, и количество записей в функцию add.Выделяю память из кучи для количества элементов увеличенных на один. Копирую записи из старой структуры в новую, и заношу новый элемент в новый массив структур. Предполагаю, что неправильно передаю структуру данных в функцию save. И под со
Тут я понимаю, что не правильно копирую структуры.

После смещаю указатель на количество существующих записей и записываю в конец новую. Отправляю исходный указатель в функцию save, с увеличенным числом записей на 1.  Программа после ввода новых данных аварийно завершается.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define path "people.txt"

typedef struct
{
    char name[16];
    char last_name[16];
    int age;
} person;

int count(char * filename);
person* load(char * filename);
void view(person *ptr, int n);
int save(char * filename, person *p, int n);
int add(person *p, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int p_menu, n;      
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1. Dobavit zapis.\n");
        printf("2. Udalit zapis.\n");
        printf("3. Redoktirovat zapis.\n");
        printf("4. Vivod vseh zapisey.\n");
        printf("5. Sortirovka zapisey.\n");
        printf("6. Spravka po rabote BD.\n");
        printf("7. Vihod iz programi.\n");
        printf("Vvedite punkt menu:\n");
        scanf("%d", &p_menu);       
        switch(p_menu){
            case 1:
                n = count(path);
                person * temp_pers = load(path);
                add(temp_pers, n);
                free(temp_pers);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                n = count(path);
                person * temp_person = load(path);
                view(temp_person, n);
                free(temp_person);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Exit\n");
                exit(1);                
            default:
                printf("Vi vveli nepravilniy nomer\n");
        }   
    }   
    return 1;
}

//получаем количество записей
int count(char * filename)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int n;    
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
         perror("Error occured while opening file");
         exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &n);        
    fclose(fp);
    return n;
}
// загрузка из файла структуры
person* load(char * filename)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int n, i=0;    
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
         perror("Error occured while opening file");
         exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &n);
    person * temp_person = malloc(n*sizeof(person));
    if ( ! temp_person )
        return NULL; // если памяти не хватило.
    while(i<n){
        fscanf(fp, "%s%s%d", temp_person[i].name, temp_person[i].last_name, &temp_person[i].age);
        i++;
    }    
    fclose(fp);
    return temp_person;
}
//просмотр считанной из файла структуры
void view(person *p, int n)
{
    int i=0;
    printf(" ---------------------------------------------------- \n");
    printf("|      name       |       last_name       |    age   |\n");
    printf(" ---------------------------------------------------- \n");

    while(i<n){
        printf("| %-16s| %-22s| %-9d|\n", p[i].name, p[i].last_name, p[i].age);
        printf(" ---------------------------------------------------- \n");
        i++;
    }
}
// запись структуры в файл
int save(char * filename, person *p, int n)
{
    FILE * fp;    
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return 1;
    }    
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", n);
    int i = 0;
    while (i<n) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s %s %d\n", p[i].name, p[i].last_name, p[i].age); 
        i++;
    }    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int add(person *p, int n)
{
    int i=0;
    person * temp_person = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(person));
    while(i<(n+1)){
            srtcpy(temp_person[i].name, p[i].name);
            strcpy(temp_person[i].last_name, p[i].last_name);
            temp_person[i].age = p[i].age;
            i++;
    }
    person * temp_person = p + n;
    printf("Vvedite name:\n");
    scanf("%s", temp_person->name);
    printf("Vvedite last_name:\n");
    scanf("%s", temp_person->last_name);
    printf("Vvedite age:\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp_person->age);
    save(path, p, (n+1));
    printf("Zapis dobavlena:\n");
    free(temp_person);
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: Удалил первую функцию

Comment: Тогда в main нужно удалить команду `free(temp_pers);` после добавления. Там указатель уже другой или удалён.

Comment: Спасибо, понял о чём вы говорите.

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаёте новый массив и тут-же удаляете, причём думаете, что количество добавили. Два определения переменной - синтаксическая ошибка.

```
person * temp_person = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(person));
person * temp_person = p + n;
free(temp_person);
```

Удалять нужно не новый массив, а старый. Причём, возвращать из функции нужно обязательно этот новый массив для фиксации в вызывающую функцию. Примерно так :

```
temp_pers = add(temp_pers, n);
```

Копирование нового массива это очень хорошо, но можно сделать это попроще с помощью `новый массив = realloc(старый массив,новый размер);`.

Comment: Возвращать новый массив не надо. Главное его зафиксировать в файле. Обращение к данным идёт через файл. И я вызываю функцию save chfpe в функции add.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось))) Спасибо за совет с realocc()
Сделал так

```
int add(person *p, int n)
{
    int i=0;
    person * temp_person = realloc(p, ((n+1)*sizeof(person)));
    temp_person = temp_person + n;
    printf("Vvedite name:\n");
    scanf("%s", temp_person->name);
    printf("Vvedite last_name:\n");
    scanf("%s", temp_person->last_name);
    printf("Vvedite age:\n");
    scanf("%d", &temp_person->age);
    temp_person = temp_person - n;
    save(path, temp_person, (n+1));
    printf("Zapis dobavlena:\n");
    free(temp_person);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: удалять теперь не надо `temp_person` а возвращать из функции этот новый адрес.

Comment: Возвращать новый массив не надо. Я его сохраняю в файле функцией save, до того как удаляю его.